# Rewrite .htaccess file but not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wish to rewrite this url:

`http://salessurface.com/overseas/sub_page_details/MBBSAbroad/MBBS-in-UK/7`

into:

`http://salessurface.com/overseas/sub_page_details.php?sup_menu=MBBS%20Abroad&menu=MBBS-in-UK&main_menu_id=7`

I tried adding the following to the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ overseas/sub_page_details.php?sup_menu=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ overseas/index.php?sup_menu=$1&menu=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ overseas/index.php?
sup_menu=$1&menu=$2&main_menu_id=$3 [L]
```

but it is not working.

How do I accomplish that rewrite?

Comment: Shouldn't the last `RewriteRule` be `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$` as the 2nd and 3rd are identical regular expressions?

Comment: not working though

Comment: Does it work if you remove the last two rules and only keep the first?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the conditions, you can do that with just a rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^overseas/sub_page_details/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) /overseas/sub_page_details.php?sup_menu=$1&menu=$2&main_menu_id=$3 [NC,L]
```

This will take the path after `sub_page_details` and put the first part in `sup_menu`, the second part in `menu` and third part in `main_menu_id`.

But I noted that in your sample URLs you use `MBBS%20Abroad` in the real URL but `MBBSAbroad` in the rewritten URL, if this is not a typo and the real URL has an space on it that doesn't have the rewritten URL then you need to use a less specific rewrite for that option:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^overseas/sub_page_details/MBBSAbroad/(.*)/(.*) /overseas/sub_page_details.php?sup_menu=MBBS\ Abroad&menu=$1&main_menu_id=$2 [NC,L]
```

This will hard code the `sup_menu` part of the URL and take the path after `MBBSAbroad` and put the first part in `menu` and second part in `main_menu_id`.